# system log not perpetually scrolling?

Tags: kernel, system, rsyslog

rsystemlogd is installed - when running - then system log
is scrolling too with kernel.log and logging of eth0.

Now it happens that system log is not scrolling despite of that rsystemlogd
is still running in background.

do I need to configure system log as daemon ? then it would
run and scroll perpetually ? why is system log stopping ?

(sorry have forgotten: it is Ubuntu 12.10 here up-to-date)

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but is auto-scroll enabled in System Log? ("System Log" on menu bar -> "Auto Scroll"; or F8 on keyboard to toggle)

Comment: yes auto-scroll is enabled - but I forgot to say: that today there was signal 15 ending the scrolling - but where does signal 15 come from ?